# Example of function with these features

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I am looking for an actual example of a convex function which has the following properties.

$f''(x)>0$

$f'(0)\approx0$

$f'(1)\approx\infty$

It's easy to come up with an example which satisfies the first two:

$f(x)=x^{2}$

But the last one is not easy.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What does it mean to be roughly infinity?

Comment: perhaps he means the limit of the function?

Comment: If you are looking for a sequence $\{f_n\}$ satisfying the first two properties such that $f'_n(1) \to \infty$ there  is a very simple example: $f_n(x)=nx^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a domain, but if $[-1,1]$ is OK then $\sec(2x/\pi)$ has the required properties.

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x) = 1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
satisfies 
$$f'(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\;\;\text{and}\;\;
f''(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}^3}$$
and its domain is the closed interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f:(-\infty,1)\to(-\infty,\infty)$ defined as
$$f(x)=-\log(-x+1)$$

Comment: This does not satisfy the second condition.

Answer (score -1):

You do not specify a domain. But from $0$ to $π/2$, the function $\tan x$ satisfies all your requirements nicely.

The domain is an important part of any function. Are you working with complex numbers or just real ones? In what domain do you need this function to operate?

Also, within what range (assuming you're working on the real line) do you want the approximation $g(x)\approx0$ to fall?